# How to set a variable after x seconds?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm basically trying to accomplish the following. I want it so 5 seconds after the page loads, it'll set the variable to true.

Once true, it'll proceed to give the alert "true".. for now. If someone tries to click the button before 5 seconds, it'll give the alert false.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but you have a minor issue with variable scope. To reduce headaches, it's really best to get away from using the string eval option on `setTimeout` (which is shown in tutorials all around the web, I know) and use an anonymous function:

```
var link;
function loading(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        link = true; 
    }, 5000);
}
```

This way, you'll know exactly where `link` is declared and the scope is crystal clear.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() { window.link = true; }, 5000);
```

This will set the global variable "link" to true after 5 seconds, which will satisfy your if statement.

**Edit**
This may be a bit complicated if you're a beginner, but a better way to accomplish this is to use function-scope rather than global scope.

In your case, declare the timer function like this:

```
var timer = (function () {
    var link = false;
    setTimeout(function() { link = true; }, 5000);

    return function() {
        alert(link);
    };
}());
```

This way, the anonymous function returns another function which becomes timer(), but this way timer has access to its "private" link variable. For more information, check out [Mozilla's article on JavaScript variable scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Functions)

Comment: Marius, while I appreciate you making the effort to edit, the curly brace you removed is a necessary part of the code (it closes the initial function block)

Rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

Simple one-liner timeout:

```js
setTimeout(() => alert("Time is up!"), 1000);
```

You can obviously execute any code within:

```js
let seconds = 5;
let timer = setInterval(() => console.log(`${seconds--} seconds left`), 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(timer);
  console.log('')
}, 5999);
```