# Changing a boolean variable 10 secs after page load

Tags: javascript

How can I allow it to be true first then after 10 secs, it will become false?

```
MemoryGame.Card = function(value) {
this.value = value;
this.isRevealed = false;

this.reveal = function() {
this.isRevealed = true;
}

this.conceal = function() {
this.isRevealed = false;
}
};
```

Comment: use `setTimeout` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: You can use the setTimeout function to wait 10 seconds and then do something to change it.

Comment: see this:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740618/basic-javascript-question-after-5-seconds-set-variable-to-true

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a variable after x seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740618/how-to-set-a-variable-after-x-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [Window setTimeout() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). So your code may be something like:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { conceal(); }, 10000);
```

Comment: Please post the answer as an 'answer' to the question, if you want to give suggestions, use the comments

Comment: you shouldn't make an anonymous function just to call another function. You should do this

window.setTimeout(conceal(), 10000);